# Trying to insert data in SQL server from Android app using WebService

Tags: java, android, sql, multithreading, web-services

```
public String SQLInsert(String Conn, String Query)
{
   SoapObject request = new          
   SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("Conn");
    pi.setValue(Conn);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("Query");
    pi.setValue(Query);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new  SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
    Object response = null;

    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
        response = envelope.getResponse();

    }catch(Exception exception){
        response = exception.toString();
    }
    return response.toString();
}  

response = envelope.getResponse();// error occurs at this line.
```

Sometimes it used to show `java.net.SockettimeoutException` and now it shows `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.I want a good solution which can help me in a long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now it shows `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Actually the above exception will come only when you are executing network related code in Main Thread so to overcome this issue you have to use either `Thread` or `AsyncTask`.

```
Thread t=new Thread(){
 public void run(){
     SQLInsert(Conn,Query);
 }
 }
```

So if you want to execute SQLInsert(-,-) method just start the `Thread` as follows

```
t.start();
```

Hope this will helps you.